# Why can you put multiple characters in C++ char*

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

I can't figure out how this works.

```
// This doesn't work (obviously)
char a;
a = "aaa";

// This works
char* a;
a = "aaa";
```

How come this works ?

Since `char` type stores only one character or 1 byte number, how can you store more characters in it when you access it through a pointer ?

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work as of the latest C++ standard.

Comment: @chris would it work if changed to `const char *a;` instead?

Comment: @greatwolf, Yes, it would.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not putting characters into the `char*`.  You're creating an array of characters in a part of memory determined by your compiler, and pointing the `char*` at the first character of that array.

The array is actually const, so you shouldn't be able to assign it to a non-const pointer.  But due to historical reasons, you still can in many C++ implementations.  However, it was officially made illegal in C++11.

Comment: And assigning it that way (string literal to `char*`) is, in simple terms, not recommended.

Comment: Okay I understand it now. I don't really use it this way, but I was wondering whats happening there. Is this inconsistent with the other data types or is there something I am not seeing ?

Comment: @Python- : It is consistent with the behavior of pointers and arrays in general (ignoring the const issues).  That is to say, if you have an array of `T` called `arr`, and a `T*` called `ptr`, the assignment: `ptr = arr;` is legal and assigns `ptr` to point to `arr[0]`.  However, pointers and arrays, *especially* arrays, have many behaviors which are not consistent with the behavior of normal objects, and you should go out of your way to avoid them, unless you are intimately familiar with their ins and outs.

Comment: @Python- To summarize @Benjamin's last statement, always use `std::string` or other string types that wrap and abstracts the honorifics of pointers and arrays. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The second one is a pointer to a string of chars, not a single char. [Tutorial.](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/string/intro/)

Comment: It's still a pointer to a single character. That character is interpreted as the first of a string.

Comment: @kmort: Technically, it's a pointer to a `char`, not a string of `char`s. Only if the pointed-at memory is a `char` sequence ending with a `\0`, then the sequence is a "string" in C terminology.